# Ubuntu Server ethernet configuration naming error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, network-interface, ethernet

I just installed the Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and wanted to configure my ethernet connection. My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auth eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.99 *whatever my ip is*
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.999 *my router's ip*
post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
dns-nameservers *my router's ip* 8.8.8.8
```

This gave my ethernet connections weird names such as *emp2s0*, *virbr0* etc. 
Based on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628217/use-of-predictable-network-interface-names-with-alternate-kernels) however `biosdevname` doesn't exist in my installation neither are any rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. What should I do to get an ethernet connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for you now is simply replacing eth0 with the actual name Ubuntu gave your device (both lines). You mention emp2s0, but I suspect it should be enp2s0.

Also, the `auth` should be `auto`

If you really dislike the new naming scheme, you can follow the many different howto's, but this will solve your immediate issue.

As clarification, this naming scheme is new in Ubuntu (since somewhere in 15) and doesn't occur on machines updated from 14, only on new installs

Comment: Thank you @madeddie .. Why is this new naming scheme adopted btw?

Comment: mostly because of the fact that if you have multiple network interfaces in your machine, it's practically relatively hard to give the same interface the same name every time you boot. They've come up with the predictable naming scheme, which is discussed in-depth here https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/